# Databricks Kusto connector: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Tags: azure-databricks

I am using Databricks on Azure and trying to run this one simple line:

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
```

However it gives me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

I have installed the following Maven libraries:

```
com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-data:2.1.1
com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-ingest:2.1.1
com.microsoft.azure.kusto:spark-kusto-connector1.1.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok I solved it. The online documentation is not very clear so pretty sure I won't be the only one having this issue.

The Maven library is for Scala (I think), not Python. To install the equivalent library in Python use PyPy to install:

```
azure-kusto-data
```

and

```
azure-kusto-ingest
```

Comment: Thanks for this; had an incredibly frustrating time following the so-called documentation to realize this is actually the answer for Python users in databricks.